# RaphaelJS+Jquery : Illusion of Drag and Drop

Tags: jquery, svg, drag-and-drop

So, I have a bunch of buttons, I want the user to be able to drag one of  them to my Raphael paper and have raphael draw a circle, or some sort of shape at the final coordinates. I also want that if they were to click on the button instead of dragging, it should place the same symbol at a pre-set location.

I realize that there have been similar questions, and I looked at them, but I have no idea why some of their examples don't seem to work.

I apologize if I am a little verbose - I'm very new to web development and a little overwhelmed by all the overloading.

Here's the JQuery I am using-

```
$(function() {
    var cnvH =$("#thisisthemainrow").height();
    var cnvW =$("#canvas").width();
    /*grabs height and width of container element*/

    var paper = new Raphael($("#canvas")[0],cnvW,cnvH); 
    insertSymbols(paper, cnvW, cnvH);
});
function insertSymbols(paper, cnvW, cnvH){
//symbol 1
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    var isDragging = false;
    $("#symbol1")
         .mousedown(function() {
             $(window).mousemove(function() {
             isDragging = true;
             $(window).unbind("mousemove");
             });
         })
        .mouseup(function(e) {
            var wasDragging = isDragging;
            isDragging = false;
            $(window).unbind("mousemove");
            if (!wasDragging) {
                 x = cnvW/4;
                 y = cnvH/4;
            }
            else{
                x = e.pageX;
                y = e.pageY;
            }
        });
   if(x!=0 && y!=0){
       var foo = drawSymbol(paper, x, y, 50);
       foo.show();
   }

};
var drawSymbol=function(paper, x,y, radius){
    var circ=paper.circle(x,y,radius);
    circ.hide();
    return circ;

};
```

The buttons themselves are defined using Twitter Bootstrapp for example -

```
<button class="btn btn-large btn-block" type="button" id = "symbol1"><a href="#">Symbol 1</a></button>
```

Comment: I found a solution. Apparently, because x and y were always 0, the draw function never executed. by moving the call to drawsymbol inside the callback to the mouseup handler, and unbinding the mouseup, i was able to solve the issue.